# How To Determine If Youtube Channel is auto generated or not through API

Tags: youtube-api

I'm getting a feed of youtube XML data through Gnip. It's their v2.0 API. I need to figure out if the source of the message is from a real user with a real user ID or is an auto generated user with an auto generated ID. Looking at it by eye, it's pretty obvious which one is a real ID and which one is auto generated but I see no fields in the XML that indicates whether the user is real or auto generated.

Example:
auto generated: http://www.youtube.com/channel/5l8cCviw5TIKtWo9VKhfZQ
real: http://www.youtube.com/{real user name}

The difference is also obvious through the link because one contains the word "channel" while the other does not. However, I do not get this information from the XML feed. I can only get their user name which is either a real name or an auto generated one. How do I distinguish between the 2?

Answer (score 0):

I think your assumption that one is "real" and the other is auto-generated is incorrect. As far as I can tell, http://www.youtube.com/channel/5l8cCviw5TIKtWo9VKhfZQ is a real user's channel. It's just that the user has a Google+ identity, and not a YouTube username. This is explained a bit more in this blog post: http://apiblog.youtube.com/2012/03/youtube-google-api-and-you.html

My main question is why do you need to distinguish? If you work solely with user ids, you should be able to treat either type of channel identically—even channels associated with YouTube usernames have user ids as well.