# How to find if a channel is auto generated (topic) by YouTube

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I have a requirement to check if a channel has been auto generated by youtube. Is there any API to check this ? How can I do this.

I have noticed that these channels have a suffix (Topic) in their channel title. But is there anyway I can check if a channel is a normal user channel or auto generated by youtube. Ex - https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCSkJDgBGvNOEXSQl4YNjDtQ/

I hope someone can help me. Thanks.

Comment: It seems that you share the same question with this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13755372/how-to-determine-if-youtube-channel-is-auto-generated-or-not-through-api). If you're asking because you want to work with autogenerated youtube channels [check this out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22596385/youtube-data-api-v3-get-video-feeds-of-auto-generated-channels).

Comment: No I'm not looking to work with auto generated channels. Infact I want something to not use them. Right now I get all kinds of channels user or auto generated. So I need a way to know if it is auto generated so that I can skip these channels.

Answer (score 0):

> YouTube has auto-generated channels of trending and popular videos
>   that are created by algorithms. On these channels, you'll see a notice
>   in the "About" section that they've been auto-generated by YouTube.

[Auto-generated topic channels](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2579942?hl=en)

And the text in "About" section can be read through API by checking its "snippet" part.

My temporary solution to this question, is just checking if there is "generated automatically" and "YouTube's video discovery system" keywords in channels description.

If any other better solution is found, will update this later.